# If the modern airliner was redesigned from scratch, would it look functionally different?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, jet-engine, aircraft-performance, wing

If the modern airliner (Boeing/Airbus) was redesigned from scratch today without any need for "backward compatibility", would it look functionally different from the current design? And if so, what would be different?

Comment: What do you mean by backward compatibility?

Comment: It's more so a programming term, but meaning the newly designed airliner wouldn't have to be adapted/fitted to any sort of current technology or processes, like airport runway lengths, airport gates, hangar fittings, fuel/electrical connections, etc; starting with a completely fresh slate.

Answer (score 4):

You'll only get opinions here, but from 40 years in the business, my opinion is not much.  Airplanes are a balance of compromises and after much trial and error, dead ends, and false starts, a combination hits a sweet spot in the balancing act and that becomes a near universal configuration.  When someone deviates, it MAY create a new configuration paradigm, but most of the time the reasons the universal configuration works so well are revealed, or rediscovered, by deficiencies in the attempt to strike out on a new path.

And here we are, still building airplanes along the lines of the granddaddy of them all for this particular configuration, the [B-47](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-47_Stratojet), 73 years later.  Virtually all of the improvements that have followed are related to engines, materials and electronics.

Interestingly, you have a kind of mirror image of the same thing in the bizjet world.  There, the tail mounted twin with fuselage hugging the ground is the design config sweet spot.

Comment: Although, it will be interesting to see if the front mounted canard will have much of an impact on biz jets compared to the rear mounted, negative lift horizontal stabilizer.

Comment: Been done.  Nearly bankrupted Beechcraft.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beechcraft_Starship

Comment: I’ve seen one of these many times at KADS. I’m not sure if it’s based there. I will get the tail number next time I see it. It is a shame that the market timing was off. I like the concept of the canard.

Comment: The problem was it was overweight, expensive, and the theoretical performance benefit wasn't there so what was the point.  The Piaggio is more successful at this, although it's not a pure canard, but more of a hybrid.  The Piaggio's secret is a carefully profiled forward fuselage that achieves laminar flow for a lot of its length.

Comment: I’ll have to see if I’m mistaking the plane at KADS for a Piaggio.

Comment: One problem with the Piaggio and the Starship is the main tires right in front of the props.  Better have surgically clean runways, and forget about gravel ops.